# Delete Committed Files in SVN with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn

I am using Eclipse Version: Kepler Service Release 2 Build and using SVN. I have created a subfolder and have files in the subfolder and have committed these files to the repo. However, I decided I do not need the subfolder and files in there anymore.

I right clicked on the subfolder and pressed Delete and it deleted the files locally. However, it did not prompt me if I wanted to commit the deletes. I checked SVN repo and the files are there.

How do I commit the deletes so it is removed from the repo using Eclipse?

Comment: Did you try to right-click the folder of the deleted files and choosing _Team > Commit_? By the way, Eclipse Kepler is pretty old. Don't waste time with outdated software.

Comment: Hi
That worked thank you. Yes will consider upgrading Eclipse into something more current.